# Firebase crashlytics not submitting exception

Tags: android, crashlytics-android

So i just added Firebase crashlytics in my app.

I use Retrofit to make api calls to and i made an interceptor that checks if there is an internet connection and if not it throws a custom exception

```
private val appContext = context.applicationContext

override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
    if (!isOnline())
        throw NoConnectivityException()
    return chain.proceed(chain.request())

}

private fun isOnline(): Boolean {
    val connectivityManager = appContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    val networkInfo = connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo
    return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected
}
```

When there is no internet connection and the exception is thrown i get the following error in the Logcat from Crashlytics

```
E/CrashlyticsCore: Error occurred sending report com.crashlytics.android.core.SessionReport@551ed2d
```

Ive tried googling for an answer but haven't found anything. Can anyone guide me as to why i get this error?

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue,
for Firebase Crashlytics api it's fatal issue as another runtime exceptions
I can offer you to use this code
`FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException("your exception instance here")`

this will make your exception non fatal